# Can someone help me find the bug? Python Turtle

Tags: python-3.7, turtle-graphics

Hello im working on a **tic-tac-toe** game and my board isn't woking correctly. Can someone help me? Im working on it in a **website called repl.it**. Heres the link : https://repl.it/@JustCoding123/Help
. The concept is that you put down **X or O -s with the numbers from 1-9** I got the board working but the **X and O didnt show**. Thanks for helping have a nice day.  And sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

A few things are causing problems:

- You're using a global `counter` instead of looping through the grid. This is always putting the next move in the next cell instead of the selected cell.
- You aren't swapping turns, the player is always 'X'
- This check always returns True: `board[0] != "X" or "O"`. Each condition is evaluated separately and any non-empty string (like 'O') is considered True. This would be more accurate: `board[0] != "X" and board[0] != "O"`

Here is the updated code (condensed):

```
def update_board():
  pen.clear()
  global turn
  print(board)
  for counter, cur_char in enumerate(board):  #starts with 0
    counter += 1  # start with 1
    if counter == 1:
      pen.penup()
      pen.setpos(-100, 80)
      pen.write(cur_char, align="center", font=("Comic Sans MS",50,"normal"))
    ...............  same for 2-8
    if counter == 9:
      pen.setpos(100, -130)
      pen.write(cur_char, align="center", font=("Comic Sans MS",50,"normal"))

  if turn=='X':  # switch turn
      turn='O'
  else:
      turn='X'
  print("Updated Board")
      

def pr1():
  if board[0] not in ["X","O"]: # same as board[0] != "X" and board[0] != "O"
    board[0] = turn
    update_board()
  else:
    print("There are already something at space 1")
.............  same for pr2-pr8
def pr9():
  if board[8] not in ["X","O"]:
    board[8] = turn
    update_board()
  else:
    print("There are already something at space 9")
............
```

[image: TicTacToe]